# Recursively create same class during instantiation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a json config that I want to create a dict from. Because json configs are recursive, any time I see a json value that is an array I want to recursively iterate on it. However this is not doing what I want it to do.

```
class FieldHandler():
    formfields = {}

    def __init__(self, fields):
        for field in fields:
            options = self.get_options(field)
            f = getattr(self, "create_field_for_" +
                        field['type'])(field, options)
            self.formfields[field['name']] = f

    def get_options(self, field):
        options = {}
        options['label'] = field['name']
        options['help_text'] = field.get("help_text", None)
        options['required'] = bool(field.get("required", 0))
        return options

    def create_field_for_string(self, field, options):
        options['max_length'] = int(field.get("max_length", "20"))
        return django.forms.CharField(**options)

    def create_field_for_int(self, field, options):
            options['max_value'] = int(field.get("max_value", "999999999"))
            options['min_value'] = int(field.get("min_value", "-999999999"))
            return django.forms.IntegerField(**options)

    def create_field_for_array(self, field, options):
            fh = FieldHandler(field['elements'])
            return fh
```

and instantiating:

```
fh = FieldHandler([
    {'type': 'string', 'name': 'position'}, 
    {'type': 'array', 'name': 'calendar', 'elements': [
        {'type': 'string', 'name': 'country'},    
        {'type': 'string', 'name': 'url'},
    ]},
    {'type': 'int', 'name': 'maxSize'}
])
```

I expect to get a dict like so:

```
{
   'position': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10b57af50>, 
   'calendar': <__main__.FieldHandler instance at 0x10b57c680>, 
   'maxSize': <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x10b58e050>, 
}
```

Where calendar itself is expected to be:

```
{
   'url': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10b58e150>, 
   'country': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10b58e0d0>
}
```

Instead I get:

```
{
   'url': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10b58e150>, 
   'position': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10b57af50>, 
   'calendar': <__main__.FieldHandler instance at 0x10b57c680>, 
   'maxSize': <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x10b58e050>, 
   'country': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x10b58e0d0>
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are the `position` and `country` parameters being set on my global `FieldHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formfields` is a class attribute that is shared among all instances. Make it an instance attribute instead:

```
class FieldHandler():

    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.formfields = {}
        # ...
```

Now, all `FieldHandler` instances have their own `formfields`, with only the "inner" calendar handler having the `country` and `url` (not `position` assuming that was a typo) fields.